# Bad name binding in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

When entering the following definition

```
datatype env = "nat => 'a option"
```

Isabelle/jedit shows an exclamation mark and says

```
Legacy feature! Bad name binding: "nat => 'a option"
```

What is the problem and how can I fix this type synonym?

Update: even

```
datatype 'a env = "nat => 'a option"
```

which is better a definition in theory did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the right-hand side of a `datatype` definition, you normally list the constructors of the datatype. In your example, you have not written any constructor, so `datatype` thinks that you want to call it `nat => 'a option`, which is not a legal name for a constructor or any other Isabelle constant.

If you just want to introduce `env` as a type abbreviation for `nat => 'a option`, `type_synonym` is what you are looking for.

```
type_synonym 'a env = "nat => 'a option"
```

Note that you have to repeat all type variables on the left-hand side. Then, `'a env` and `nat => 'a option` can be used interchangeably. If you want to introduce a new type constructor for `env`, then you must provide a constructor name such as `Env`:

```
datatype 'a env = Env "nat => 'a option"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was exeperimenting with typedef and was not aware of type_synonym.

Comment: `typedef` is something different: it defines a type as a subset of another pre‑existing set type (the defined subset has to be proved non‑empty). See “11.5 Typedef axiomatization” in `isar-ref.pdf` for more. This is part of some may‑be confusing vocabulary Isabelle uses :-P .